# Why do Xavier and Magneto meet Wolverine in "The Wolverine (2013)"?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine, x-men-days-of-future-past

From what I understood from X-Men: Days of Future Past, it happens in the future, many years after The Wolverine (2013). Why then do Xavier and Magneto meet Logan in 2013? They must have been sent back in time by Kitty to warn Logan, but why warn him in 2013, and then take his help only many years later (ie., in DOFP)?

Comment: How did you deduce that they have been sent back by *Kitty*? I thought they merely recruited him for their purpose, anticipating the danger of the upcoming *Sentinels*. That war (and that earth) doesn't seem to have taken just some weeks anyway.

Comment: I think that the scene was just supposed to be a tease for DOFP. Bryan Singer was expected to explain and correct continuity errors but his movie created more questions than it answered.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that they merely knew the Sentinels were becoming more and more advanced.

We see the Mark I Sentinels in 1973 with the Mark X (ha!) being the super-powered ones we see in 2023-D (D meaning the Dystopian future).

Considering this scene with them recruiting Wolverine takes place in 2015-D we can assume the Sentinel program is probably advanced to a point and revealed at a point around this time that Charles & Erik realize they need to put aside their differences, team up, and get every mutant they know about to join their cause and prepare for a fight together as a mutant force.

Comment: Yes, that's what I inferred too, but what would they have told Logan?
"Hey, we just came along to warn you to be on the lookout for nasty Sentinels that Trask has started manufacturing. Meanwhile, we'll be sending your future self into the past to change the current timeline. I guess that's about it. See ya later!"

Comment: Ah, alright I think I get what you're saying. They could have come along to inform him that they're still alive and kicking and that he should probably find their 2013/2015 counterparts and join forces.

Comment: @user9871 Kitty Pryde states she *cannot* send anyone back more than a month due to severe mental damage, hence why Logan was chosen to go back to 1973.  Since they are in 2023-D, then it is actually the *actual* 2015-D versions of Charles & Erik that track down Logan to recruit him to their "army".

Comment: @user9871 I don't think the possiblity of sending *Logan* (or anyone) back to the 70s wasn't even known (let alone considered) up until the point where they meet *Kitty* and decide to do it.